Language-Ext- How do i get just the error message from an Error Type from Validation<Error,T>
In using LanguageExt, I am trying to display just the error message of a failed validation from using Validation<Error,Unit> in LanguageExt.
However, I get the following string:

ValidationData(Fail, 0, [Starting number is not a valid number])

I can't seem to find a way to get just the error message which is

Starting number is not a valid number

Can anyone provide any advice on how to do this?
Here's a snippet of the code
ValidateStartingNumberError(int number)
    .Match(
        () => None,
        error => DisplayError(error.ToString())
    );

private Validation<Error, Unit> ValidateStartingNumberError(int number)
    => int.TryParse(this.number, out var parsedNumber) ?
         unit :
         Fail<Error,Unit>("Starting number is not a valid number");

private void DisplayError(string message)=> MessageBox.Show(message);


What is DisplayError and what is Fail<Error,Unit>?

Sample code for DisplayError included. Fail<Error,Unit> is a class part of Language-Ext library

How can you call a class? Or did you miss the new keyword?

Found the reason: I implemented the wrong .Match(...). It should be
ValidateStartingNumberError(int number)
    .Match(
        _ => None,
        error => DisplayError(error.Head.Message)
    );


Looking at the documentation I think that you need the Message property:
ValidateStartingNumberError(int number)
    .Match(
        () => None,
        error => DisplayError(error.Message)
    );


Unfortunately, using error.Message does not compile.
